# IOS: action with enter key of iPad KeyBoard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have two textfield, in first textfield I write "Hello" and when I push enter in iPad keyboard, I want that in second textfield appear "World"; How can I use enter to create an action in my application?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You would typically assign your view controller as the text field's delegate and then implement the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method, e.g.:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    otherTextField.text = @"World"
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: ah ok I didn't write textFiled.delegate = self;

Comment: Footprint in Swift is `func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool`

Answer (score 9):

You can do that by implementing the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol in your controller.  For instance you could do something like:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == theFirstTextField && [textField.text isEqualToString:@"Hello"]) {
        theSecondTextField.text = @"World";
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your view controller to be the textfield's delegate then implement

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

this gets called when the enter button is pushed on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This is roughly what you'd do. Tweaking to condition around device-type (if you truly want iPad only):

```
#pragma mark - UITextField Delegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    if (textField == self.firstTextField && [textField.text isEqualToString:@"Hello"]) {
        self.secondTextField.text = @"World";
    }
    return YES;
}
```